# GNU diff3 (three-way merge) gives unexpected result

Tags: merge, gnu, diff3

Assume that files MINE and YOURS are descendants of OLD.

FILE_MINE=

```
abc
def
ghi
```

FILE_OLD=

```
abc
jkl
ghi
```

FILE_YOURS=

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Command `diff3 -m MIND OLD YOURS` gives:

```
abc
<<<<<<< OLD
jkl
=======
def
>>>>>>> YOURS
ghi
```

diff3 cannot resolve that MINE and YOURS made identical changes.

Why?  And, is there a way to resolve this issue?

Tickle your brain with this:

`diff OLD MIND` and `diff OLD YOURS` have identical hunks in their output.

```
2c2
< jkl
---
> def
```

Should these hunks not "cancel-out" during the three-way merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What did you expect to have?

As the [article describing diff3 utility](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/diff3-Merging.html#diff3-Merging) says:

> ... This (merging) **fails to be true** when all three input files differ or **when only older differs**; we call this a *conflict*. When all three input files differ, we call the conflict an *overlap*

Therefore, the case you've described is treated as a conflict. 'Why so?' you might ask. Because of the diff3 algorithm. Description you can find at the same page:

> You can think of this (merging) as subtracting *older* from *yours* and adding the result to *mine*, or as merging into mine the changes that would turn older into yours

It cannot resolve differences properly because it does not have a proper context of changes being made.

I would agree with you if you're going to say that it should work using some other approach. But... it is what it is. diff3 is not perfect, I would recommend using other tools if you want to do it right as described in the [article](http://www.guiffy.com/SureMergeWP.html)