# What is the difference between 'diff3' and 'svn merge' commands?

Tags: svn, diff, merge

Is there any difference between the algorithm of how `diff3` utility and `svn merge` commands work?  Does `svn merge` use the same principle or some variation of how `diff3` works? For example, `diff3` [does not automatically merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931490/gnu-diff3-three-way-merge-gives-unexpected-result/5017780#5017780) changes if *mine* and *theirs* files have the same content while `svn up` or `svn merge` does.

My question is also closely related to the automatic merging. How does it work? When conflict happens and when it does not? It's obvious that conflict happens when the same lines of source code have been edited, but there are cases when it is impossible to define merge context? How `svn merge` defines it?

I've found following passage at the ['Copying Changes Between Branches'](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch04s03.html) page from svn book:

> ...svn diff only outputs the limited
>   patch-format, so there are some ideas
>   it simply can't express. The svn
>   merge command, however, can express
>   tree-changes by directly applying them
>   to your working copy

What are all those differences? I cannot find detailed info anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difference is that `svn merge` command can express tree-changes while `svn diff` can not. Detailed answer can be found after deep analysis of svn source code.